# Four Dimensional Pandas DataFrame Error "Must Pass 2-D Input"

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

I am trying to debug the following when importing MATLAB file in python pandas and converting to CSV and got this error:

> ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(170, 7, 3, 3)

**Here's my code**

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd

data=loadmat (r"/Users/a/desktop/file.mat")

x= data ["file"]
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_csv(r"/Users/a/desktop/data.csv")
```

Comment: Could you please post an example of what is the data you're importing and also the complete traceback of the error?

Comment: Pandas is built to work with 2 dimensional data. For `n-`dimensional data, prefer numpy's ndarray.